# Create custom event that would work for any selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have this senseless script that changes the background color of an element when it's clicked:

```
$(".foo").on("change.color", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".foo").click(function() {
  $(this).trigger("change.color");
});
```

As for now it works for the `.foo` element only due to this line:

```
$(".foo").on("change.color", function() { ... }
```

The question is how do I transform the line above to make it work with any selector I wish to use later, e.g.:

```
$(any_selector_here).click(function() {
  $(this).trigger("change.color");
});
```

Comment: You could add the `foo` class to the selectors that you want event to be attached to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the `foo` `className` to `any_selector_here`

```
$(document).on("change.color", ".foo", function() { });

$(selectors).addClass("foo");
```

which would allow you to remove the `className` of specific elements, detaching event listener from those elements

```
$(any_selector_here).removeClass("foo");
```

Comment: No, I don't want to add any classes, I just want to change the background of an element clicked (not exactly, just to simplify things).

Comment: @Deka87 Adding the `className` is for purpose of attaching event to element or elements. The original event can be attached to any `className`, for example `"colors"`. `$(document).on("change.color", ".color", function() { $(this).css("background-color", "red"); });` You can then add or remove the `className` to the elements which you want to have event attached using `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()`. `$(any_element_here).addClass("colors")`, `$(selectors).addClass("colors")`, `$(".foo").addClass("colors")`. To remove event from element, `$(any_element_here).removeClass("colors")`

Comment: Oh I see now, sorry I though there was a simplier way.

Comment: @Deka87 Well, actually there is a simpler way. Instead of attaching event to elements, you can define `css` for a class `.colors{color:red}` then add, remove the `colors` `className`. `function changeColor(e) { $(this).addClass("colors") }; $(document).on("click", ".colors", changeColor)` Do you want to apply color change to all elements in document at click on element?

Comment: That example was a simplified version of what I need, I am working on a custom "carousel" that would slide to a given slide when a button is clicked (also on other events). That's why I wanted to create a custom event that would do this, and other actions on button click.

Comment: _"I am working on a custom "carousel" that would slide to a given slide when a button is clicked (also on other events)."_ Not certain how this is related to original Question? Are you trying to attach and detach a single event listener to elements?

Comment: The original question was how to "Create custom event that would work for any selector". And yes to your second question.

Comment: `javascript` at original Question does not achieve this? `$(document).on("click", ".colors", changeColor)` pattern should return expected result. By adding, removing `className` the event will be attached, detached to that specific element

Comment: If I state $(".foo_alt").trigger("change.color") it just work work.

Comment: _"If I state $(".foo_alt").trigger("change.color") it just work work."_ ? What is expected result of `$(".foo_alt").trigger("change.color")` call? To call event handler for all `.foo_alt` elements?

Comment: I guess I am too bad in JS to explain it better, sorry.

Comment: If you use `$(document).on("change.color", ".foo", changeColor)`, note reference to `.foo` at second parameter, you can call `$(".foo_alt").addClass("foo").trigger("change.color")`

Comment: Your are right, this will change the color of a given element, I just thought there was a way to create an event that would work with any selector given, not just .foo.

Comment: Like $("button").trigger("click"). This will work weather the selector is button or "a" or any other tag.

Comment: You can select all elements with selector `"*"` if that is what you really want to do `$("*").on("change.color",  changeColor)`

Comment: _"Like $("button").trigger("click"). This will work weather the selector is button or "a" or any other tag"_ Not certain what you mean?

Comment: haha lol this pretty much answers my question. I never thought of * for some reason!

Comment: I meant that the click event would be triggered on BUTTON or any other selector is is called for!

Comment: Yes. If an event is attached to `<button>` or other element at selector

Comment: I guess I am too bad in JS to explain it better, however the "*" trick you suggested worked like a charm. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking your easiest approach might be to simply listen on the body and route the trigger.

```
// Listen for click on the biggest element possible (like the body)
$('body').click(function(event){
     // event.target is the actual element
     $(event.target).trigger("change.color");
});
```

If you're looking to change the element clicked, specifically, then you might be able to completely forgo the "change.color":

```
$('body').click(function(event){
     $(event.target).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: may be [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) is a better idea.

Comment: @Redu That would be `body`. Not the most useful.